# In Jekyll Blogs how is "paginator" populated?

Tags: pagination, blogs, jekyll

I am working on my own plugin that allows me to add a whole new post type called "log" which gets rendered out to a different directory and is effectively a completely different area.

I have everything working nicely with the exception of pagination.

I can't not for the life of me figure out how `paginator` in the following line gets populated

`{% for post in paginator.posts %}`

Where in the jekyll code is paginator?!

`posts` get paginated but I need my `logs` to get paginated too.

Can someone tell me where in the site payload or loading process the paginator gets stuffed so that I can add my logs type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is in [jekyll paginate plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate)

Comment: As far as I can tell, I do not have that gem installed yet pagination works fine.  Is this gem jammed into the jekyll gem?  Or is it a prereq or something?  `gem list` doesn't show it installed at all.

Comment: Oh nope.. I stand corrected it is installed it just wasn't with the rest of the gems in the list.. my bad.